# Making NSWindow to refuse keyboard events

Tags: macos, cocoa, events, nswindow

I have an application and my requirement is to have a window on top but it should refuse all keyboard events. How can I do this ??

Comment: What have you tried? What documentation have you read? What have you searched for?

Answer (score 1):

You could override acceptsFirstResponder: with return value of NO on it's content view.